# Passing object variable to onchange event JS

Tags: javascript, function, events, scope, socket.io

I've been browsing around for an answer to this question for a little while now, but haven't found a solution. I need to pass an object to a function which is being fired "onChange" when a select option is chosen by a user. The current code is:

```
selecter.onchange = function(){
        var runScript = $("#actionSel option:selected").attr('script');
        console.log(runScript);
        eval("("+runScript+")();");
    }
```

The intention here is to store a function within the "script" attr of the options, which will then be run when that option is selected. However, for one of my functions I need to pass a variable from the parent scope on in order to interact with the server via websockets.

The function stored in the "Script" attribute is :

```
function(){ popConfirm("Restore User","Do you really want to restore the selected users? This will un-delete the selected deleted users.",function(r){ if(r)restoreUser(r,io); });
```

Essentially this verifies with the user that they want to do what they've selected, then passes the result to my restore user function. It also needs to pass the "io" object on. However, I'm getting an error which states that io is undefined.

Any ideas would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

As requested, here are some additional relative pieces of code showing where IO is introduced.

```
AdminIO = new io(servPath);
AdminIO.on('send_users',function(rows){
     toggleLoad();
     appendUsers(rows,AdminIO);       
});
```

Within appendUsers there's another function which compiles the select list and its options, dropActions(), wherein the selector.onchange and other piece I posted before are introduced. The selector.onchange is part of the function that creates the dropdown list. The function(){ popConfirm() } is added as the function to run on selection of that item. The function to build the list is :

```
dropActions = function(bActions, lActions, options){
    // bActions = {id: myID, text: "this is my action", elem: document.getElementById('getDiv'), action: function(){ /*mycode here */}}
    // lActions = {text: "select me to run an action", action: function(){ /*mycode here */}}
    bActions = bActions || null;
    lActions = lActions || null;
    options = options || {elem: document.body, id: null};
    if(!bActions && !lActions){ console.error("No actions added or available."); return; }

    var 
        selID = options.id,
        starter = (selID) ? document.getElementById(selID) : options.elem,
        optsBar = document.createElement("header"),
        selecter = document.createElement("select");
        starterSel = document.createElement("option");
    optsBar.id = "actionSelH";
    starterSel.innerText = "More Actions";
    starterSel.setAttribute('script','javascript:void(0)');
    selecter.id = "actionSel";
    selecter.appendChild(starterSel);
    for(var i= 0; bActions.length > i; i++){
        var 
            buttonText = bActions[i].text,
            buttonID = bActions[i].id || 'ACT'+i,
            buttonAction = bActions[i].action,
            button = document.createElement('div');
       button.id = buttonID;
       button.classList.add("actionButton");
       button.innerText = buttonText;
       button.onclick = buttonAction;      
       optsBar.appendChild(button);
    }
    for(var i= 0; lActions.length > i; i++){
        var selText = lActions[i].text,
            selScript = lActions[i].action,
            option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerText = selText;
        option.setAttribute('script',selScript);
        selecter.appendChild(option);
    }
    selecter.onchange = function(){
        var runScript = $("#actionSel option:selected").attr('script');
        console.log(runScript);
        eval("("+runScript+")();");
    }
    optsBar.appendChild(selecter);
    $(optsBar).insertBefore('#user_list_table');
    //$('#user_list_table').after(optsBar);
    //$(starter).prepend(optsBar);  
},
```

Hopefully more context helps!

Comment: Is it possible for you to pass the function directly in JavaScript without using HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, you could use the [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and pass your parameters directly to that function:

```
var scriptFunction = new Function(r, io, runScript);
scriptFunction(r, io);
```

Of course, this code assume that `r` and `io` will always be the variable you are looking for.  If this ain't the case, you'll have to write your own logic to take the variable from the parent scope and then pass them to the `scriptFunction`.

**Update**

If you are able ton change the provided script, you could also try to implicitly declare the variables `r` and `io`:

```
function(r, io){ popConfirm("Restore User","Do you really want to restore the selected users? This will un-delete the selected deleted users.",function(r, io){ if(r)restoreUser(r,io); });
```

Comment: Interesting thought. Unfortunately it looks like this has the same problem. R is fine, since it's part of the overall function context. But io is in the parent context, which apparently can't be accessed from the event. Essentially I would love to get this to work in the same way that binding an onclick works... Since that works fine doing the same thing with a button.

Comment: It would be helpful to get the whole context.  Can you update your code to show us how and when `io` is declared?

Comment: I can, but it may just be more confusing... The excerpts I have up there now are within builder functions which create my select statement. I'll post a higher level a little later today when I can get to a system that has the code on it.

Comment: You don't have to post the entire code; just the relevant parts (you can hardcode the part where `io` gets declared).  The important thing is to show us what is the exact relation between `io` and the script

Comment: Accepting your answer as it got me to where I needed to go. I used the function constructor as suggestion and just modified my script to bind an "args" variable generically. It's clunky... But it works. Thanks!